# Why does my Angular project appends links and scripts in index.html when building?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli, angular7

Recently I have been installing packages in my Angular Material project

Amazing Time Picker, Bootstrap Timepicker, etc.

And after I try them but doesn't work for my Angular project, I uninstall them. Right now I am using the Material Ngx Time Picker. Everything works fine in local and during build time. But project won't run in the deployment environment, I have the following errors

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://52.198.226.3:3000/styles.939548ba4f5da0a64386.css".
runtime.1e53f64d47e84fba89ef.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.011c9e0c53dcff7183b4.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.dc0fd4587ec9ba4ad746.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

And I found out in my `index.html` that there is a `<link>` and a `<script>` appended but isn't in my source code editor. These are the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.939548ba4f5da0a64386.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.1e53f64d47e84fba89ef.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.011c9e0c53dcff7183b4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.dc0fd4587ec9ba4ad746.js"></script>
```

And these are basically the errors found in the console but I did not add these manually. How to remove these?

Comment: Delete your node_modules and install again to your local machine

Comment: Okay I will try it

Comment: Thank you. I deleted node modules then installed it back. I also checked in my .gitignore dist was ignored,

Comment: Now is it working?